# Ajax dropdown selection using arrow key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created an ajax dropdown, i need to change the background color of the dropdown values when i press the down arrow and up arrow key.Here when i press the key background changes and it disappears immediately.it's not working in the ajax dropdown, if i put and alert before setting the class selectedhash, it's working else it's not working.

Here the div will be updated by the ajax results with list.

Please help me to solve this.

```
  <div class='textautocomplete'>
  </div>


 $(document).on("keydown", function(e) { 
 if (e.keyCode == 40) 
 { 
 if(chosen === "")  
 {
 chosen = 0;

 } else if((chosen+1) < $('.textautocomplete ul').length) 
 {
 chosen++; 
 }
 $('.textautocomplete ul').removeClass('selectedhash');
 $('.textautocomplete ul:eq('+chosen+')').addClass('selectedhash');

 return false;
 }
 if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
 if(chosen === "") {
 chosen = 0;
 } else if(chosen > 0) {
 chosen--;            
 }
 $('.textautocomplete ul').removeClass('selectedhash');
 $('.textautocomplete ul:eq('+chosen+')').addClass('selectedhash');
 return false;
 }
 });


  $(".textinput").live("keyup",function(e)
  {
  $.post('/users/getusers',{data:dataString},function(result){
  if(result!=='') 
  {
  $('.textautocomplete').show();
  $('.textautocomplete').html(result);
  }
  else
  {
  $('.textautocomplete').hide();
  $('.textautocomplete').html('');
  }
  });
  return false
  });
```

Comment: Please set up a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change: ".live" to: ".on" in line:

```
$(".textinput").live("keyup",function(e)
```

because:

```
"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."
```

More: [jQuery .live() method](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

Secondly add keyCode filter code in:

```
$(".textinput")
```

For example:

```
if ( e . keyCode == 38  || e . keyCode == 40 ) { return false; }
```

Working example fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vc7pH/)